# Can you launch Hyper-V without enabling Virtualization?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2019, nested-virtualization

I want to allow hyperv to launch so that we can have hyper-v roles in windows, but don't need full on virtualization.

- The reason I don't want the full on virtualization capabilities is because im running hyper-v in an *already* nested virtualized environment, and it doesn't appear that i can 'double nest' virtual machines (if im mistaken here, please let me know) !
- Another reason why I may not want full virtualization is that ultimately Im not **actually** using Hyper-v to make VMs.

Thus, my question is:

Is there a way to configure Hyper-V to only enable roles, or HNS, while disabling other, 'non virtualization' related functionality, so that it starts properly in a nested environment where 2nd level virtualization isnt enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V supports Nested virtualization, allowing to run Hyper-V inside of
a Hyper-V virtual machine.

The main condition is that the Hyper-V host and guest must
**both be Windows Server 2016/Windows 10** Anniversary Update or later.

If this interests you, see the article
[Run Hyper-V in a Virtual Machine with Nested Virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization).

Comment: does this mean that you cannot nest hyper-v inside of a vsphere ESXi host ?

Comment: See [How to Run Nested Hyper-V on VMware vSphere](http://www.vmwarearena.com/how-to-run-nested-hyper-v-on-vmware-vsphere/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to configure Hyper-V to only enable roles, or HNS, while disabling other, 'non virtualization' related functionality, so that it starts properly in a nested environment where 2nd level virtualization isn't enabled?

This is not possible.  The user roles require Hyper-V to be enabled on the machine.

> The reason I don't want the full on virtualization capabilities is because I'm running hyper-v in an already nested virtualized environment, and it doesn't appear that I can 'double nest' virtual machines (if im mistaken here, please let me know) !

Hyper-V supports nested hardware virtualization.  You must be running a supported version of Windows 10 or Windows Server.